# What have I done wrong with my collision detection?

Tags: c++, collision, sfml, detection

I want to program a game. I have already programmed enemies and a player. Whenever the game objects, it doesn't matter whether enemy or player, move against the cornors (left and top or right and top or left and bottom or right and bottom), the game objects move outside of the field.

There is also a second problem. Sometimes, the enemies stick in the edge of the field for a short time

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Player.hpp"
#include "Square.hpp"

#define WIDTH 800
#define HEIGHT 600

bool kUp = false, kDown = false, kLeft = false, kRight = false;

Player player(WIDTH / 2 - 10, HEIGHT / 2 - 10, 10, sf::Color::Green);
std::vector<Square> squares(10);

sf::RenderWindow window;

void update(float elapsedTime) {
    if (kUp == true) player.move(0, -300.0f * elapsedTime);
    if (kDown == true) player.move(0, 300.0f * elapsedTime);
    if (kLeft == true) player.move(-300.0f * elapsedTime, 0);
    if (kRight == true) player.move(300.0f * elapsedTime, 0);

    sf::Vector2f playerPos = player.getPosition();
    if (playerPos.x < 0) player.setPosition(0, playerPos.y);
    if (playerPos.y < 0) player.setPosition(playerPos.x, 0);
    if (playerPos.x > WIDTH - 20) player.setPosition(WIDTH - 20, playerPos.y);
    if (playerPos.y > HEIGHT - 20) player.setPosition(playerPos.x, HEIGHT - 20);

    for (int i = 0; i < squares.size(); ++i) {
        sf::Vector2f squareSpeed = squares[i].getSpeed();
        squares[i].move(squareSpeed.x * elapsedTime, squareSpeed.y * elapsedTime);

        sf::Vector2f squarePos = squares[i].getPosition();
        if (squarePos.x < 0) squares[i].setSpeed(-squareSpeed.x, squareSpeed.y);
        if (squarePos.y < 0) squares[i].setSpeed(squareSpeed.x, -squareSpeed.y);
        if (squarePos.x > WIDTH - 5) squares[i].setSpeed(-squareSpeed.x, squareSpeed.y);
        if (squarePos.y > HEIGHT - 5) squares[i].setSpeed(squareSpeed.x, -squareSpeed.y);
    }
}

void draw() {
    for (int i = 0; i < squares.size(); ++i) {
        window.draw(squares[i]);
    }

    window.draw(player);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow) {
    sf::ContextSettings settings;
    settings.antialiasingLevel = 8;

    window.create(sf::VideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT), "Runner - The Red Squares", sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close, settings);
    window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);

    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < squares.size(); ++i) {
        squares[i] = Square(rand() % WIDTH, rand() % HEIGHT, 5, 5, sf::Color::Red);
    }

    sf::Clock clock;
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Time elapsedTime = clock.restart();

        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

        update(elapsedTime.asSeconds());
        draw();

        window.display();

        sf::Event evt;
        while (window.pollEvent(evt)) {
            if (evt.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }

            if (evt.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) {
                if (evt.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Up) kUp = true;
                if (evt.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Down) kDown = true;
                if (evt.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Left) kLeft = true;
                if (evt.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Right) kRight = true;
            }

            if (evt.type == sf::Event::KeyReleased) {
                if (evt.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Up) kUp = false;
                if (evt.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Down) kDown = false;
                if (evt.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Left) kLeft = false;
                if (evt.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Right) kRight = false;
            }
        }

        sf::sleep(sf::milliseconds(15));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Thanks for each help

Comment: Consider:  does `playerPos` equal the value from `player.getPosition()` after calling `player.setPosition()`?  If necessary, use your debugger to see.

Comment: Consider the case when a square is "outisde" but its velocity isn't high enough to move it back "inside" on the next frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you're using a copy of the player position (stored in `playerPos`) while also updating the current player position (using `player.getPosition()`).  If the `x` and `y` positions are both negative, you'll initially set the player `x` position to 0.  In the next line, since `y` is negative, you set the player position to a 0 `y` but the old *still negative* `x` position from the copy.

There are several possible solutions, including always getting the player position (and not using the copy) or adding a way to only set the player `x` or `y` position without having to set both.